# How to set up a hash field in phpmyadmin/sql?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to know that is it possible using SQL in PHPmyAdmin to be able to get a field to display only hash characters or something like this so that unauthorised users would not be able to see those characters in letters and numbers? This is for a password field I am creating.

Thanks

Comment: If this is for storing the passwords securely, [check out this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, yes, MySQL has hashing functions. They are listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

However, if you really want to store your passwords securely, read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database).

**UPDATE**

Say, for example, you're using `SHA2()` to hash your passwords (use your own judgement after reading the above article to determine which hashing algorithm to use).

To compare an authentication string (read: "User-entered password from login screen") to the stored password (read: "Password that the original user entered as his/her password"), you would do something like this pseudocode:

```
$passwordHash       = getPasswordForUser($userName);
$authenticationHash = sha2($authenticationPassword);

if ($passwordHash === $authenticationHash) {
    // successful login. do something here.
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I am a little bit confused, so is it not as simple as using `PASSWORD(str)?` OR in other words `SELECT PASSWORD('TeacherPassword')`

Comment: From the MySQL manual: **Note**
The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider `MD5()` or `SHA2()` instead. Also see RFC 2195, section 2 (Challenge-Response Authentication Mechanism (CRAM)), for more information about handling passwords and authentication securely in your applications.

Comment: Hash functions tend to be *one-way* algorithms. In order to compare an authentication string against the stored password, you have to perform a hash on the authentication string, then compare the hash to the stored password (which has already been hashed).

Comment: I added to my answer to help clarify.

Comment: OK so first of all use SHA2() or MD5() in phpmyadmin and then use code you have showed me in the php script to compare passwords. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Did you read the [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)?

Comment: When you insert the password use `INSERT INTO table_name (userid_column, username_column, password_column) VALUE (user_id, username, [HASH](password_string))` and that will "encrypt" your user's password.

Comment: If you have used PHPmyAdmin before, what do I actually change the data type to in the drop down menu? Or do I have to change it to SHA2 using SQL code?

Comment: So you cannot insert a hash password by using phpmyadmin insert? only by sql coding

Comment: phpmyadmin can execute straight sql queries. It just tends to let you use its GUI to make life easier.

Comment: Before I mark your answer, to update the field so it makes the "TeacherPassword" field into a hash field, how is it done? I tried this but did not work: `UPDATE Teacher
SET [HASH](TeacherPassword)`

Comment: replace `[HASH]` with whichever hash function you've decided to use (i.e. `MD5()` **which is not recommended**, `SHA2()`, etc.).